# hook ZwTerminateProcess , in fake function find PID

Tags: windows, hook, driver, kernel

```
NTSTATUS fakeZwCreateProcess(HANDLE ProcessHandle , NTSTATUS ExitStatus )
  {

  }
```

ProcessHandle  is handle (kernel handle) to process it will terminate, how find PID from it

i need for

```
if(mypid==pid_from_handle)
{
```

Comment: SSDT hook or what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ZwQueryInformationProcess(ProcessBasicInformation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687420.aspx)